# Nested loop and optimization

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I have following loop in python

```py
for port in list_ports:
   (...)
   for protocol in list_protocols:
      (...)
```

Above nested loop return a **boolean** variable called `token_found`.
Now in case `token_found` is *False* I need to repeat above nested loop but in reverse way:

```py
for protocol in list_protocols:
   (...)
   for port in list_port:
      (...)
```

Is there any suggestion on how can I avoid the second nested loop and apply some logic already inside the first nested loop?

Comment: Depending on the structure of your data, it might also be worth it to look into vectorised functions or at least structured calls such as done in `pandas'` `apply`-method. But from the outside it is not clear why reversing the order of the loops helps to find something that previously wasn't there.

Comment: in somehow you answer as I checked pandas than dataframe and searching i realised that itertools.permutation is perfect for avoid my nested loop. I basically have 2 array of service_port and protocol and i need to find if any service is defined in iana registry for each combination port/protocol. permutation did the job